# Type mismatch: inferred type id <no name provided> but OnProdukItemClickListener was expected

Tags: mysql, android-studio, kotlin

so I'm making a simple marketplace-like program, where the database is from MySQL, and in this project i'm adding the onClick function on recyclerView where it takes the user to the detail of the product

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONObjectRequestListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.produk_list.*
import org.json.JSONObject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnProdukItemClickListenener {
    lateinit var produklist: ArrayList<Produk>

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        produklist = ArrayList()

        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, 1))
        recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(produklist, this)

        val produk=ArrayList<Produk>()

        AndroidNetworking.post("http://192.168.100.8/farminc/freshproduk.php")
            .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(object : JSONObjectRequestListener {
                override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject) {

                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)

                        var idPrdk = jsonObject.optString("id_produk").toString()
                        var imagePrdk =jsonObject.optString("image").toString()
                        var namaPrdk = jsonObject.optString("nama_produk").toString()
                        var hargaPrdk = jsonObject.optString("harga").toString()

                        produk.add(Produk("$idPrdk", "$imagePrdk", "$namaPrdk", "$hargaPrdk"))

                    }
                    recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(produklist, this) ***<--problem source***
                }

                override fun onError(error: ANError) { // handle error
                }

            })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(produk: Produk, position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, produk.nama_produk, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.kt**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.produk_list.view.*

class CustomAdapter (var produk: ArrayList<Produk>, var clickListenener: OnProdukItemClickListenener):RecyclerView.Adapter<ProdukViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return produk.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProdukViewHolder {
        val v=LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.produk_list, parent, false)
        return ProdukViewHolder(v)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProdukViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.initialize(produk.get(position), clickListenener)

    }

    interface OnProdukItemClickLictener {
        fun onItemClick(produk: Produk, position: Int)
    }

}

class ProdukViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var imagePrdk = itemView.imagePrdk
    var namaPrdk = itemView.namaPrdk
    var hargaPrdk = itemView.hargaPrdk

    fun initialize(produk: Produk, action: OnProdukItemClickListenener) {
        imagePrdk.text = produk.image
        namaPrdk.text = produk.nama_produk
        hargaPrdk.text = produk.harga

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            action.onItemClick(produk, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}

interface OnProdukItemClickListenener {
    fun onItemClick(produk: Produk, position: Int)
}
```

**Produk.kt**

```
data class  Produk(val id: String, val image : String, val nama_produk:String, val harga: String) {
}
```

and the source of the problem is the `recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(produklist, this)` in MainActivity, thanks.

Comment: Please provide stacktrace and compact your code by removing redundant parts like imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling this inside of the implementation of `JSONObjectRequestListener` which is not of type `OnProdukItemClickListenener` and referencing it using this keyword.

You should point to the MainActivity because that is the implementation of `OnProdukItemClickListenener`

**Like this:**

```kotlin
recyclerView.adapter = CustomAdapter(produklist, this@MainActivity)
```

This is called [Qualified this expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) and are used to point to a specific object using the this keyword.

Comment: so the one i have to change are OnProdukItemListener to JSONObjectRequestListener, and add the @MainActivity right?

Comment: also the thing that i don't mention is i have another activity (SearchActivity.kt)  similar to the main activity, the only difference is the other on is to search, so do i also have to add the @SearchActivity on the search one?

Comment: @Luthfi Kusumajadi you've just gotta add `@MainActivity`

Comment: You need to exlplicitly mark the object whereever `this` keyword is overridden by some child class.

Comment: thanks tho I removes all my errors tho, but when i run the app the recyclerview didn't show the items from my database. any idea?

Comment: @Luthfi Kusumajadi probably because you're adding items to produk while passing produklist into the adapter.